# How to correctly nest slots in child elements when using Stencil.js?

Tags: web-component, stenciljs

I know that if I have a `<slot />` inside my component, I can then insert content from the HTML, but I don't understand how this works.

For example:

```js
      render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <slot />
          </div>
        )
      }
```

Now, inside my HTML, I can do this:

```html
<my-card>test</my-card>
```

and "test" will be inserted as a content.

However, if the `<slot />` is nested inside other child-elements inside my component, the "test" text is still inserted even if it's not inside those particular elements. How does that work?

For example:

```js
      render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <button><slot /></button>
            <select>
              <option value="one"><slot /></option>
            </select>
            <p><slot /></p>
          </div>
        )
      }
```

Now, in my HTML, if I do this:

```html
<my-card>test</my-card>
```

The text "test" is inserted inside the `<slot />` inside the button. But what if I want to add text inside the `<option> <slot />`? How do I do that?

If I only have one `<slot />` inside `<option>` for example, how do I insert text inside of it from my HTML?

Comment: You have two **unnamed** ``<slot />``  in your example; there can only be one.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman If I give my slots a name, how do I then reference them in my HTML?

Comment: Maybe the Fine Manual helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I tried it, but it's not working!! In my component tsx, I have a button whose innerHTML is a slot, and then I also have a `<select>` with 3 `<option>`, one of which has a `<slot />`. In my HTML, I did `<slot name="two"><option>test</option></slot>` and when I inspect the page, the slot is again added inside the button, which has the first `<slot>` but with a different name! Why?

Comment: Just to be clear, in my component tsx, all slots have a unique name, and yet, in my HTML, `<span name="two">fsfs</slot> is again inserted inside the first <slot> with a name "one", and not the second <slot> with a name "two". Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can only have a single unnamed slot. Any additional slots have to have a name:

```
<slot name="outside" />
```

To add an element inside a named slot you can use the `slot` attribute:

```
<my-card>
  <span slot="outside">test</span>
</my-card>
```

See also [Stencil's documentation on slots](https://stenciljs.com/docs/templating-jsx#slots).

Comment: Why is it not working for me?? Just to be clear, the `<my-card>` component is in normal HTML, not inside any JS framework!

Comment: It's hard to say without more code. Can you try to create a minimal reproduction of the issue on [webcomponents.dev](https://webcomponents.dev/)?

Comment: I already figured it out. It was because I was using `<select>`, which is not slottable.

Comment: But now I have another issue with the classes. Can you try answering this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75131443/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-slotted-element